# Combinatorics involving a poker hand

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, card-games, poker

How many 5 card poker hands can be dealt from a standard deck of 52 cards with 3 hearts and 2 diamonds?

I have tried this but I am not sure if it is correct:

${13\choose3}{13\choose2} = 22308$

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is correct. To specify a $5$-card poker hand with three hearts and to diamonds, you need to choose the three hearts present in $\binom{13}3$ ways, and then choose the two hearts present in $\binom{13}2$ ways. Since the hearts can be chosen independently of the diamonds, the total number of ways is found by multiplying the number of ways to do each.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct.  The general principle is the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution), and the probability for $0$ spades, $3$ hearts, $2$ diamonds, and $0$ clubs is
$$\frac{\binom{13}{0}\binom{13}{3}\binom{13}{2}\binom{13}{0}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$